# How can I play a local .avi extension video in my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, jupyter-notebook

I can a local video with `.mp4` or `.mov` extension with

```
from IPython.display import Video

Video("example.mp4")
```

or

```
from IPython.display import Video

Video("example.mov")
```

but I can't display `.avi` extension videos on my Jupyter Notebook using Python 3.7.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: The browser (`<video>`) must support it first. Perhaps you have to install some proprietary video driver for the browser (or use a different browser).